# Add discuss.area51 to the list of viewable sites on the Android app

Tags: feature-request, area-51, android-app

I understand why Area 51 isn't viewable in the Android app - it's running on different software and all that. However, isn't it the case that [Area 51 Discussions](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/) runs on the standard software? If so, could it be made viewable in the Android app?

Comment: I don't believe either of the Area 51 sites is exposed via the API.

Comment: @animuson Ooh, yeah, you're right. [`/sites`](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/sites) doesn't include either Area 51 site in its result set.